# How come I can't import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils?

Tags: java, classpath

[image]

I added the common lang jar file in the classpath, but when I compile it says:

error: package org.apache.commons.lang does not exist

I tried to follow the steps described below:

http://oopbook.com/java-classpath-2/classpath-in-jcreator/

but I don't it doesn't work. Is it the editor that's not working properly or is it something else?

Comment: Which version of the jar did you get? The newer versions have a different packaging structure (org.apache.commons.lang3 instead of org.apache.commons.lang).

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi  i am not sure, but i think i downloaded this one.

Comment: is it possible that it's because i am using windows 8 or something. I don't know how that could possibly affect the compiler, but maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Between major versions 2 and 3 apache changed the package naming scheme on their classes from **lang** to **lang3**.

Notice on the download site that for version 2.6 you are downloading "commons-**lang**-2.6" and for version 3.3.2 you are downloading "commons-**lang3**-3.3.2".

Also, if you check out [the current API doc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/index.html) you'll see the new naming structure.

All you need to do is update your import statement to match the new package structure and your compiler will be able resolve it correctly.